# Can't get a value of a variable from a class

Tags: python

This is some code I wrote to understand how a global variable works.

I can't get any value for `aaa` in `print('fuera ' , aaa)`. I am not sure how the sequence of execution happens either.

```
import tkinter as tk
global aaa

def primero():
    winda = tk.Toplevel()
    def on_button():
        global aaa
        aaa = entry.get()
        winda.destroy()

    entry = tk.Entry(winda)
    button = tk.Button(winda, text="Get", command=on_button)
    button.pack()
    entry.insert(0,'nada')
    entry.pack()
    entry.focus_set()

windo = tk.Tk()
primero()
print ('fuera ', aaa) 
windo.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need the global keyword for a variable already in the global scope... Second line

Comment: You don't start the event loop until *after* the `print()` call, so you can't have hit the button yet either.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how the sequence of execution happens

Basically, you are starting a window with a button first. Simple enough. Meanwhile, the code after you initialize the window, i.e. the print statement, continues to run, but `aaa` is only ever initialized when you click the button.

Therefore the error.

In the bigger picture, here, GUI events are making the learning of global variables more complex than necessary

If you'd like to fix the problem, simply initialize `aaa`

```
import tkinter as tk
aaa = None
```

If you'd like to watch this global variable change, add another print statement inside the button click

Comment: Criket, thanks. I understand that i can print aaa inside the button click. My question is how do i get it out of the button if i want to use aaa in other parts of the program. That is why I add the print after calling the method primero. I thought aaa would come from primero with a value to show. thanks

Comment: Then you should define a function that you pass `aaa` into as a parameter. The error that you are getting is because `aaa` is not defined at the point of the print statement, but only after you click the button (if you ever do)

Comment: Criket. Thanks. Isn't that function on_button??? why do i have to create another one. Once I do on_button, the global aaa should be known everywhere, or not?

Comment: You don't have to but you asked *how do i get it out of the button... and use in other parts of the program*. I would encourage you to use functions instead of depending on global variables.